# DateWise data display in gridview

Tags: asp.net, date, gridview, header

How to show DateWise data in Gridview in asp.net.Means dats should be in   header when we click on any month.
like

```
Broadcast 1jan 2jan 3jan.........
 abc        0    1    0
 xyz        0    1    1
```

Comment: Please explain your question clearly , it would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for crosstab in gridview.

I found an example of it here

http://redsouljaz.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/asp-net-cross-tab-pivot-from-data-table/

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/266719-Bind-crosstab-gridview-example.aspx

This is how you can write queries for crosstab in sql:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/

Comment: how to select the month and i have to use c# not vb.